# Passing further inside of template

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the same template library that phil sturgeon created and I have the following layout for my control panel. I am getting this error. I ran a var_dump on the template variable inside the control panel controller and it showed the string of the control panel view but when I do the same thing inside of the content view it says there was no body index. I would like to know how I can pass the data to the content view.

Any ideas for me?

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: body

Filename: partials/content.php

Line Number: 8
```

Control Panel Controller

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Controlpanel extends Backend_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->template
            ->title('Control Panel')
            ->set_layout('controlpanel')
            ->set_partial('header', 'partials/header')
            ->set_partial('sidebar', 'partials/sidebar')
            ->set_partial('breadcrumbs', 'partials/breadcrumbs')
            ->set_partial('content', 'partials/content')
            ->set('user_data', $this->users_model->get($this->session->userdata('uid')))
            ->build('dashboard');
    }
}
```

content.php

```
<div id="content">

    <!--    Insert Header    -->
    <?php echo $template['partials']['breadcrumbs']; ?>

    <div class="separator bottom"></div>

    <?php echo $template['body']; ?>

</div>
```

I've tried looking into this and still haven't found a solution. I was hoping someone else might see something I am not.

Comment: I haven't used that library before but it looks interesting. Based on the documentation my guess would be that partials don't have a 'body' variable automatically set like templates. Try something like this? `set_partial('content', 'partials/content', array('user_data'=>...))`

Comment: Yeah for some reason I tried some stuff like that and didn't get anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use his library too, and got some ploblems when passing objects through

```
$this->template->set('data_name', $my_object);
```

just cast it to array.

```
$this->template->set('data_name', (array) $my_object);
```

Comment: I guess I'm just confused because what I mean is I have my template and with the build method it tells it what view will be loaded but with my control panel template it has a header, sidebar, and content partials. Inside of the content partial is the breadcrumb partial and the body area which is what the build is supposed to get.

Comment: Just tried it here. I think you can't have template['body'] in a partial. Is there any place where you did that and it worked ?

Comment: I think @Klamir is right. I think you can't use also `$template['title']` (and others) in partial.

Comment: You can try `print_r($template)` in partial to see what you can use.

Comment: Looking at the library code (build method) I figured that the partial view is loaded before the template['body'] variable be set, so you will not be able to send it to a partial...

Check it in the build method, maybe you can change it.

Comment: I understand that you wanna use breadcrumbs only with a few specific types of content.
So you can put your breadcrumbs partial in your template and just put a IF berofe, to test if its set, and load if true.

Answer (score 1):

THe following works for me:

```
$this->template->set('body', $body);
```

Then in my view (using the PyroCMS lex parser):

```
{{ body }}
```

Alternatively, you could assign an array to the set method:

// $page is from a db query

```
$this->template->set('page', $page);
```

Then in the view:

```
{{ page->body }}
```